# Can LRO be disabled using ethtool?

Tags: linux-networking

My NIC driver does not support H/W LRO but emulates LRO in the driver. Now GRO (which is a linux network stack feature) can be disabled using 'ethtool -k ethx gro off'. Is that available for LRO as well? i know most distros have either LRO or GRO. So if LRO is disabled using ethtool does it imply turning off the H/W LRO feature or the LRO emulation feature that i do in my driver?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with ethtool. Just make sure you have the latest version. Check the man page.